# Translating UIImageView Up

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I want to translate a UIImageView object up 70 points when my view loads.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect logoFrame = logoImage.frame;
    logoFrame.origin.y -= 70;
    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [logoImage setFrame:logoFrame];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Works when inside method besides viewDidLoad (ie touchesBegan).

Comment: Forgot to link IBOutlet with nib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` will run once the view loaded, which might be long before the view really display. If you want to make the animation when the view appears, use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` instead.